# Where to Download Microsoft Office for Mac?

Tags: macos, microsoft-office, office-for-mac, microsoft-office-2008

There used to be a Trial version of Microsoft Office 2008 for Mac. But I can not find it anymore on below official site:

http://www.microsoft.com/mac/downloads

The are mostly the updates. I can not find the original Office 2008 download. What am I doing wrong and where can I find the trial version of Office for Mac?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft seems to have removed it from their site. However, you can download it from [Softonic](http://microsoft-office-2008-trial.en.softonic.com/mac) (~545MB).

Comment: They are again the updates, not the default program installers

Comment: Please see the updated link.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]